# Log object not showing string value

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller, opencart

I am working in opencart. I am using log object for debugging.
i am quering my db to give me email against an id i get perfect result in my SQL DB when i run it.
but in my code em getting nothing when i print my variable.
here is my code

```
 $email=$this->db->query("SELECT email FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "shipping_pools` 
 WHERE geo_zone_id = '".$zone_id."'");
 $this->log->write($email);
```

here is an error i get in my log file

"PHP Unknown:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/ifarpart/public_html/dev/system/library/log.php on line 14"

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.
$email is not a string.

Do 

var_dump($email)

to understand what you're getting back from the query() function

Comment: i dont understand why i am getting -2 on this no one has even answered

Comment: @Jlil please explain. i dont get it

Comment: @Jlil if i could use var_dump or print_r i would have checked easily. problem is that iam working on catalog side and i cant use them . thats why i mentioned that iam using log obj to debugg

Comment: @Jlil the same query i ran in my sql was giving me perfect email

Comment: An object is not a string, and vice versa. From your question we don't know the db driver that you are using or how your query was made. So it is kinda hard to guess.

Comment: @frz3993 the same query is giving me a proper email address in sql query section.

Comment: You mean a query directly to the sql server? Of course, nothing is wrong with the query.

Comment: which framework are you using?

the `query()` is returning an object in your case.

If for example you're using codeigniter, you need to do:
`
foreach ($email->result() as $row) {
   $this->log->write($row->email);
}
`

Comment: Try adding this before the log write. `$email = $email->row['email'];`.

Comment: @frz3993 perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

The $email returns an array. You should use $email->row['email'] in order to get email as a string.